# Ho do I pass a list of secret to Azure key vault?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I want to push a list of secretes provided to me in excel all at once, since adding secretes one by one will take several hours is their any way to push them all together at once.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!)

Answer (score 7):

Azure Key Vault does not support batch operations, but you can submit them asynchronously in tools like PowerShell, or write code using the Azure SDK. This will reduce the amount of time it takes, but be aware of [service limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/key-vault/general/service-limits).

Setting a secret should only take a couple of seconds. If you project that setting many secrets will take "hours", you might instead consider bundling multiple secrets (in some format like JSON, or whatever works for your application) together. Enumerating all of them to find a single one by a prefix, for example, will take a while and is still subject to service limitations.

For example, you can export your spreadsheet as a CSV and import it into PowerShell like so:

```bsh
install-module az -force -scope currentuser
connect-azaccount # sign in
import-csv my-secrets.csv | foreach {
  $secret = convertto-securestring -string $_.Secret -asplaintext -force
  set-azkeyvaultsecret -vaultname my-vault -name $_.Name -secretvalue $secret
}
```

This assumes your CSV looks something like this (first row are column names):

```
Name, Secret
foo, asdf
bar, qwer
```

It may take some time, but apart from running as jobs and worry about rate limits, or writing your own code to better control the rate limit, this will work.

Again, though, if you have that many secrets, you might rethink bundling some together in a way that works for your application.

Comment: If someone is going to downvote, please explain why. Maybe this isn't the answer you were hoping for, but as a developer on the Key Vault SDK, I can assure you there is no REST API for bulk operations. What I presented is a solution - at workaround, at least - to the problem.

Comment: thanks Heath we tried the same approach and it worked

Comment: convertfrom-csv expects the csv as a parameter, i.e. string. For file input (as the my-secrets.csv suggests), Import-Csv should be used. This could cause someone to downvote, as the code doesn't work straight out of the box. You have my upvote, though, on a simple and working solution!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll fix that. PS's inconsistent use of convertfrom vs import verbs makes pulling code snippets OTOH difficult.